# MacBook Pro won’t turn on, even after SMC reset

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, power-management

While I was doing some basic file management in the Finder, my MacBook Pro (mid 2012) suddenly went black. It wouldn’t turn on, even after long-pressing the power button or resetting the SMC (System Management Controller). The SMC reset caused the battery indicator light to go from green to red, but even after ten minutes of supposed charging it is not responding to the power button. My symptoms are similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64080/macbook-pro-wont-power-on-after-smc-reset) and [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/221837/2011-13-macbook-pro-shows-a-green-charging-light-but-battery-was-draining-and-n) post, but I have not spilled any liquid on the computer (quite the contrary; it has been stored for over a week on a dry, high shelf), and the laptop does not react to the power button even with the power cord attached.

Do I have any other options but taking the Mac to a repair shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer in my case was **No**, there was no other option but to [change the main logic board](https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+15-Inch+Retina+Display+Mid+2012+Logic+Board+Replacement/9725). To my extreme fortune, Norwegian law requires five years of warranty on all electronics such as laptops and phones, so it was done for free. The repair shop even told me I was [eliglible for a new screen](http://www.staingate.org/) so they threw in that as well.

Update Q1 2018: And to my extreme fortune and several unexpected circumstances, now they even swapped out the battery for free. Talk about longevity :-)